# How to add folder to search path for a given Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am developing a project in Python and I want to include some own modules which are not on the regular Python search path and I want to add them. However, I want to do this just for the Anaconda environment I am using during development and I would like them to remain there over time(i.e. when I restart the environment, I want the search path to have that folder).

Thanks!

Comment: what is the advantage over simply installing them?

Comment: @cel They are my own modules and I didn't build the package for distribution.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to cleanly solve this without writing a minimal `setup.py`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use

```
conda develop <directory>
```

This will write a `conda.pth` file to the environment's site-packages directory which will cause your directory to be added to the `sys.path`.

Comment: you have to have `conda-build` installed in the conda root to have access to conda develop. Just in case anyone is wondering, like I was, why conda develop would return an error stating there is no conda develop.