# How to link handmade package with conda in a generic and clean way?

Tags: path, package, conda

Hi

I created my own package, myOwnLib. I made a link from **/path/to/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages** which point to my package, following this : [Anaconda: Permanently include external packages (like in PYTHONPATH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath).

It works perfectly when I don't activate any environment. However, When i "conda activate" an environment, I cannot access to the package anymore and receive the message : 
    "No module named 'myOwnLib'"
I can thus link this library with doing the same action **/path/to/.conda/envs/previous/lib/python3.7/site-packages/** , but it becomes redundant.

Is there a more generic way to link modules with anaconda?

Thanks in Advance

action attempted:
1) conda develop "/path/to/lib", as suggested here : [How to add folder to search path for a given Anaconda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715261/how-to-add-folder-to-search-path-for-a-given-anaconda-environment)

Comment: What went wrong with `conda develop`? In general, you have to install packages into a location that can be seen by the Python interpreter; conda environments do a lot of work to make sure they are isolated, so you have to install a package into the environment before you can use it. If you really want it to be available to all of the Pythons on your computer, you can install it into `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` (I think that's the right folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a deeper investigation, I notice that conda develop works perfectly **IF you use it outside the environnement**. Being Inside one don't offer the opportunity to do global changes on How conda manage your Python libs.

Be Carefull: I notice that I cannot use **conda develop** without having installing pip with conda before ( conda install pip) because conda install pip seems to create lot's of files such as lib, which is needed. Otherwise, you get a message that tells you that it cannot find : **path/to/your/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda.pth**