# My Python imports don't work as they should according to tutorials

Tags: python, python-import

#### Introduction

I'm having problems with importing my own modules/packages so I searched up some tutorials (written and youtube) and was trying to solve my problems. However nothing really worked so I recreated the structure of a tutorial to follow it step by step ([sweetcode.io](https://sweetcode.io/python-file-importation-multi-level-directory-modules-packages/)).

I'm using `Python 3.9.13` installed via anaconda on a win10 machine

#### Structure of the sample project

```
-- tutorial
   |-- subfolder1
   |    |-- subfolder2
   |    |   |-- __init__.py
   |    |   |-- student.py
   |    |   `-- user.py
   |    |-- __init__.py
   |    `-- item.py
   |-- subfolder3
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- accounts.py
   |   `-- registration.py
   |-- __init__.py
   `-- security.py
```

I could follow the tutorial up to the part where they talk about importing a module backwards, so say from `student.py` import the module `security.py`. However as soon as I try  to do that I get an error message.

#### Attempt 1:

code in `student.py`:

```
import tutorial.security
```

powershell command (currently inside the `tutorial` directory):

```
python .\subfolder1\subfolder2\student.py
```

error received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Schnetzubroot\Documents\test\subfolder1\subfolder2\student.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tutorial.security
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tutorial.security'
```

#### Attempt 2:

if I change the code in `student.py` to:
`from test import security`
I still get the same error message

#### Attempt 3:

When trying to use a relative import as such: `from ... import security` i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Schnetzubroot\Documents\tutorial\subfolder1\subfolder2\student.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ... import security
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it because I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Also any feedback to the post is appreciated as this is my first question here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: I'm afraid that's a very good tutorial. I find it pretty misleading about how directories relate to packages, and about how Python's import system actually works. In particular, imports _do not navigate directories_ (they are only resolved by searching the Python path), and it's incorrect about the significance of `__init__.py` files. See the linked question and the Python [import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for better coverage.

Comment: @Brian I've read the first post which you gave me ([relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)) and think I understand the mentioned difference between scripts vs. modules, but I can't figure out how that affects my example, since I just want to import the module in a "backwards kind of way" as I would if it was just in the same directory or a subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

You should not use "import tutorial.security". Instead use "import security", or just to be sure use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/21165705).

Comment: This fixes the problem for the moment. However I'm trying to achieve this without the need for the sys import, as the code gets developed on different machines and thus different paths. Is there maybe an elegant way to make this work with different machines?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that page is missing some key details for use as a true tutorial.

**Attempt 1 & 2**

The issue here seems to be that the root "tutorial" directory is not on your python path for anaconda. Instructions for doing this using Anaconda can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715261/how-to-add-folder-to-search-path-for-a-given-anaconda-environment#32748920)

**Attempt 3**

The issue here is you are trying to run the python file as a script. (i.e. `__name__ == "__main__"`. See the [Python Docs (6.4.2. Intra-package References)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) note on this. It appears  the intent for relative imports is not to be used in an Python script, only for internal uses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way of doing the 'from' import would be:

```
from tutorial import security
```

Otherwise, you can also add the parent folder 'tutorial' to your system path and then just import security directly, like so:

```
import security
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, path/to/tutorial/folder)
```

Comment: the `from tutorial import security` doesn't work and still throws an error (no module named 'tutorial').

Comment: Doing it the sys.path way does work, however is not my preferred solution as I don't want to adjust the path every time I switch machines when developing the code. Maybe there is an elegant way to solve this problem however